# I want to use InnerText Value for further calculation in Cypress

Tags: web-applications, ui-automation, cypress

So, I am able to get the innerText value of the element, but I want to use this value globally. I tried using the below code:

```
cy.get('#selector').invoke('text').then(text => {
const price = text;
});
```

How can I access the value of price in the rest of the test? Also, the value is a string, how can I change it to an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a function in `commands.js` file and call this each test. 
In commands.js file, create a 'simplePrice()' function as below:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('simplePrice', () => {
    cy.get('#selector').invoke('val').then(val => {
        const price = val;
        return price;
      })
});
```

Then in each test you can get the price value as below. The benefit of this way you can call as many times you want to get the price value. Also keep it as a common function and when you change in one place, ie commands.js,  all test receives the changes.

```
describe('Test to get the price value', ()=>{  
    it('Test-1', () => {
        cy.simplePrice().then((val)=>{
            const price_first = val;
            console.log("Hello log this one:"+price_first);  
        })  
    })

    it('Test-2', () => {
        cy.simplePrice().then((val)=>{
            const price_second = val;
            console.log("Hello value this second time:"+price_second);
        }) 
    })

})
```

Comment: The problem is the scope of the variable price. The value of the price is correct even with text, but its limited. I want to use the value of the variable in the test.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: This also won't work, because the value of the price is only available in the cy.get command function. But I want it out this, so that it can be used by other functions in the test.

Comment: I didn't get that completely. Do you mean the following test code `cy.get('#selector').invoke('text').then(text => {
const price = text;
});` is written in commands.js file ?

Comment: When we write this`cy.get('#selector').invoke('text').then(text => { const price = text; cy.log("Print total:"+total ); });`we get the value of total and everything is perfect but if we write this `cy.get('#selector').invoke('text').then(text => { const price = text; }); cy.log("Print total:"+total );` the value of total is undefined because its not available globally.

Comment: Ok, I will give you a different option, will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Its what I was looking for :)

Comment: Always glad to help

Answer (score 0):

From what I see that constant price is only gong to be available in that function. You would need to make it global/modular

```
describe('name of your test', () => {

    let price = null;

    before(()=>{

        cy.get('#selector').invoke('text').then(text => {
             price = new Number(text);
        });        

    })

});
```

Comment: When I am printing the price variable, the value is null.